# Software for user story mapping

Tags: user-interface, mind-mapping

I've recently came across Jeff Patton's brilliant concept of a [user story map](http://jpattonassociates.com/the-new-backlog/). My team/clients are all remote, and so using sticky cards won't work.

I started looking for online solutions and came across [storiesonboard](http://storiesonboard.com/). It started as a great tool, however it is only configured to work with basic story maps. More advanced story maps (ie the ones that are broken down according to user roles such as the SAP example in the book [User Story Mapping](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491904909) depicted here [image: Example map]

simply cannot work. So what I did instead is create story maps using Adobe Illustrator

[image: Illustrator example]

with its obvious limitations. Any other tool out there anyone recommends?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically missing: What OS must the software run on? How much may it cost? What are your specific requirements?

Comment: There are several tools that could work like Microsoft Visio, Lucycharts, Trello, etc., but as Izzy mentioned we need more details in order to able to give a good recommendation.

Comment: @Rubén - Lucycharts? Did you mean [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/)?

Comment: @JohnY <span>Yes</span>